# Python: Multiple connects

Tags: python, sockets

i work on a Python Daemon that connects to multiple "Clients" and listen.

Important: The Port of the Daemon must be the same for all Clients.

```
class UDPReader(asyncore.dispatcher):
        def __init__(self, local, remote, parser):
                asyncore.dispatcher.__init__(self)
                self.parser = parser
                self.create_socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
                self.bind(local)
                self.connect(remote)
```

My question is now, how can I connect to multiple "clients" at the same time and listen there with the same port? And is there a way to see, from which client the data comes?

Comment: UDP doesn't maintain connection information, it is more like an open door that shouts out information to anyone that listens and receives information from anyone that knows which door is open.

Answer (score 1):

See [socket.recvfrom()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.recvfrom) - the return value is a pair `(string, address)` where the `address` is address of the sender and something you can pass to a subsequent `socket.sendto()` call.

With UDP `connect()` doesn't really set up any connections, you can still send and receive from anywhere; all it really does is set a default destination address for socket internally and let you use `send()` or `write()` instead of passing the address explicitly every time.